# For storing answer in array and changing color of button

Tags: php, html, css

This code should change the button color when answer gets saved in database but it is not saving. Kindly help am a beginner.

```
<?php 
       $qpquery="SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM question WHERE FMid=$tid";
         $qprs=mysqli_query($conn,$qpquery) or  die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
         if ($qprs->num_rows > 0) {
             while($qpro = $qprs->fetch_assoc()) {
         $total=$qpro["total"]; 
         }  
             echo $total;
         }        
     for ($j = 1 ; $j <= $total; $j++)
         {            
?> 


<?php  echo $_SESSION['mark_ques'][$j]; 
     foreach($_SESSION['mark_ques'] as $storeanswer){
         $flag = 0;
         if ($storeanswer == $j){
             $flag = 1;
             break;
         }
     }          
        if($flag == 1){?> 

  <button type="button" class="button button5" style="background-color:Green;">
  <?php echo $j ; ?> </ton>
```

Link for the code-https://drive.google.com/file/d/108XgWQFwCqJz3y58g9SN1nu6NfbbjLKG/view?usp=sharing?

Comment: You are defining the $total variable in while loop which is not accessible outside the while.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to try it with javascrpit , try this :

```
  <button id="MyButton" type="button" class="button button5">

    <?php

        if($flag == 1){?>
            <script>
                document.getElementById("MyButton").style.background = "green";
            </script>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Sir I have added a google link to at the end of code it has all code kindly check.@EBIRAM